# Orbit-based metric

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mg.metric-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, discrete-dynamical-systems

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $f:X\rightarrow X$ be continuous.  Then, is there any meaning/research done on the metric
$$
D(x,y)\triangleq \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \frac1{2^n} d(f^n(x),f^n(y));
$$
where $f^0(x)=x$?

Comment: I assume you want $X$ uniformly bounded, otherwise the sum may not converge. Is this metric not equivalent to $d$?

Comment: Yes x2.  It is easy to see that's its equivalent to $d$ but I was wondering if there was a "similar" variant of it that defines a finer topology than $d$ does.

Comment: This metric reminds me of constructions in the proof of Bessaga theorem (the converse of Banach fixed point theorem). The point is that the metric there defined uses the max instead of a series: see equation 3.4 in [this 1967 paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/af5c/302a00bf31d3d492e0840a32a5514efdbd6a.pdf) of Meyers.

Comment: Ah, but in that case wouldn't the topology be stronger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the linear case (for a bounded operator $T$ on a Banach space), the analogous construction for equivalent norms, possibly with a different ratio in place of $1/2$, is often named *adapted norm* (see e.g. *Global stability of dynamical systems*, by Michael Shub). Its main feature is that gives $T$ an operator norm arbitrarily close to its spectral radius. For metric spaces, note that $f$ is $2$-Lipschitz wrto $D$, and that the constant $2$ may be replaced to any $\theta>1$. At least, this shows that for a continuous self-map on a metric space, or on a complete metric space, being Lipschitz is not that special, if the constant is larger that $1$.

Comment: Ah, that's interesting.  I can see how this then relates to Surb's post on the Banach fixed point theorem.